# Image Gallery without Thumbs

Tags: jquery, image, gallery, clone, appendto

I am trying to create a jQuery image gallery(I rather create one, than use a plugin)
I've looked at several different tutorials and selectors, each of which use thumbs.
Now my current code is this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('img').click(function(){
    $(this).clone().appendTo('#imageViewer').css({"opacity":1,"height":"50%"});
  })
});
```

The problem, I have it that, I cannot replace the image when another image is clicked. Is there anyway of just making it with the regular images but using CSS to shrink them i.e >height: 20%; opacity:0.2; but when clicked, they show up in a div on the page >height: 50%; opacity: 1;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see the **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ejiseg/2)**

**HTML**

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="mainImg"><img src="http://youchew.net/wiki/images/9/9c/One.png" /></div>
  <div id="allImg">
    <img src="http://youchew.net/wiki/images/9/9c/One.png" >
    <img src="http://seo-hacker.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/04/22.png" >
    <img src="http://webtrafficnews.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/3.png" >

  </div>
  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
#content {width:300px;border:solid 1px #f00;overflow:auto; margin:0 auto;}
#allImg {}
#allImg img{ float:left; width:30%;opacity:.5; cursor:pointer; margin:5px}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function(){

  $("#allImg").on("click","img",function(){
    $("#mainImg img").prop("src",$(this).prop("src"));

  });

});
```

**EDIT:**

[Updated slideDemo](http://jsbin.com/ejiseg/3/)

**CSS**

```
#mainImg {width:300px; height:300px;}
```

**Jquery**

```
$("#allImg").on("click","img",function(){
    newImage = $(this);
    $("#mainImg img").slideUp(500,function()
      {
        $("#mainImg img").prop("src",newImage.prop("src"));

       $("#mainImg img").slideDown(500);
      });

  });
```

Comment: you can add any animation you want

Comment: how would you add animation i.e >slide?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting all of the images inside of a wrapper div. Set the div to "position:relative" and the images as "position:absolute;top:0;left:0".

Then, the JavaScript:

```
var galleryImages = $('#galleryWrapper').find('img');
var firstImage = galleryImages.first(), lastImage = galleryImages.last();
var currentImage=firstImage;

//hide all images but the first
firstImage.siblings().hide();

galleryImages.click(function(){
    //hide the current image
    currentImage.hide();

    //if not last image, show the next
    if (currentImage!=lastImage){
        currentImage=currentImage.next();
        currentImage.show();
    }

    //if last image, go back to the first
    else {
        currentImage=firstImage;
        currentImage.show();
    }
});
```

Size the images in CSS however you please.